# passing in  block to method  in Ruby

Tags: ruby, higher-order-functions

I would like to pass in an generated(higher order function)  to a method to a ruby method .
Something like this

```
 [].select give_block

  def give_block 
    lambda { |e| e > 1 }  
  end
```

I get an error saying

```
"wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"
```

How could i accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[].select(&give_block)
```

will do the trick